# Como poner Imagen de fondo en ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic

bueno mi pregunta es bien simple com puedo poner una imagen de fondo? e intentando de varias maneras desde css que es lo que he encontrado pero aún nada!

Mi ruta seria: `www/img/fondos/newalgas.svg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poner una imagen de fondo debes declaras una clase css y darle la propiedad `background-image:`

```
background-image: url('../img/newalgas.svg')
```

Comment: Esto no funciona para el layout de la pagina completa.

Answer (score 1):

En la versión 4 de Ionic haz lo siguiente

En el .SCSS

```
ion-content.background{
    --background: url(www/img/fondos/newalgas.svg) 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

y en el HTML

```
<ion-content class="background">
```

Si vas a ocupar un ruta que esta dentro de tu carpeta modifica el SCSS de esta manera

```
ion-content.background{
    --background: url(../img/fondorest.jpg) 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

Solo modifica la ruta url(ruta)

Answer (score -2):

Una forma que me funcionó fue la etiqueta img:

```
<img src="img/fondos/newalgas.svg">
```